# Where can I find the code of the lock screen button in the menu?

Tags: lock-screen, menu, menu-bar

Where can I find the code of the lock screen button in the menu? I need the code about what happens when it click.

Comment: whats your ubuntu version? its hard coded in gnome-shell library files..

Comment: my ubuntu version is 19.04 @PRATAP